# cURL command line to PHP

Tags: php, curl, ssl-certificate, ssl

I have to make a request from PHP to a secure https server with a self-signed certificate. I have a working command line in cURL but have a lot of problems converting it to the correct and working PHP options.

The working cURL command is this:

```
curl --cacert cert.pem
     --key cert.key
     --cert cert.crt
     --header 'content-type: text/xml'
     -X POST
     --data @ftit-request.xml https://serverip/dip/DipWebservice > outputfile
```

Can someone give me some hints on how to use this the correct way in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, '1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  getcwd().'/cert/ca.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd().'/cert/mycert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'password');
```

Comment: That does not work, i think i am missing the --key cert.key ?

Comment: Read the article from  php doc. I show the code from http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php#84374

Comment: You nedd to create a ".pem" file

Comment: I needed te convert/join the .crt and .key to a .pem file. cat cert.crt cert.key > cert.pem. After that it worked.